# Send two audio sources over WebRTC

Tags: android, audio, webrtc

I have a WebRTC's Android application that can successfully build a WebRTC connection, but I hope it can pass the system sound and microphone sound, but I don't know what to do. I can specify the source of the audio sources as the system or microphone alone and can run normally, but how do I pass two different source at the same time?

The audio source can be specified when creating the PeerConnectionFactory.

```
val pcf = PeerConnectionFactory.builder().apply {
    val videoEncoderFactory = DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(rootEglBase?.eglBaseContext, true, true)
    val videoDecoderFactory = DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase?.eglBaseContext)
    val adm = JavaAudioDeviceModule.builder(applicationContext)
        .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC) //Or MediaRecorder.AudioSource.REMOTE_SUBMIX
        .createAudioDeviceModule()
    setVideoEncoderFactory(videoEncoderFactory)
    setVideoDecoderFactory(videoDecoderFactory)
    setAudioDeviceModule(adm)
}.createPeerConnectionFactory()

val audioSource = pcf.createAudioSource(MediaConstraints())
```